# Ogg libvorbis - how to get a bit depth

Tags: ogg

I use `ov_open_callbacks` and then `ov_info` functions to get the informations about ogg audio file. `vorbis_info` struct doesn't contain an information about a bit depth. I have to pass `word` argument to `ov_read`:

> Specifies word size. Possible arguments are 1 for 8-bit samples, or 2
> or 16-bit samples. Typical value is 2

Answer (score 1):

Vorbis stores frequency information, so there is no such concept as bit depth. Decoded data always comes out as 32-bit floating point.

ov_read is part of vorbisfile, which provides some higher-level functionality than the usual libvorbis calls. When you specify a bit-depth there, the vorbisfile code merely takes the decompressed floating point data and converts it to 8-bit or 16-bit before presenting it to you.